# Distribute an application with an embedded (OWIN) webserver with HTTPS (SSL)

Tags: c#, ssl, owin

We have developed a .NET 4.5 application that runs an embedded (OWIN) webserver on localhost.

Some of its functionality requires us to make AJAX requests to that webserver from a public website on the Internet. 
The problem is that that site uses HTTPS. Chrome now complains that there is unsafe content being loaded (which is correct).

To solve this, we would need to have our embedded webserver use SSL, so that there is no HTTPS-HTTP traffic. There are plenty of examples online of creating a self-signed certificate and binding that to a port, but our application needs to be distributed as well.

Is it possible (and how) to create a self-signed certificate for localhost (OWIN) that is actually redistributable?

I understand that this means that the connection is not trusted, because it's not verified by an SSL Authority, but we're only trying to use it so that there is no cross-protocol communication between the localhost and the public website.

Comment: Rather than trying to create a distributable self-signed certificate for localhost, I'd have thought a more sensible approach would be to generate the self-signed cert on each machine as part of the installation process.

Comment: Thanks Damien, the Internet site connects to "https://localhost", if all clients have their own machine name as their URL, the concept doesn't work anymore.

Comment: No, I would still do localhost - but I'd generate the cert during installation. That way you don't have to distribute a certificate *with private keys*, and you don't end up with (hundreds? thousands? millions?) of machines that are all trusting an identical certificate. If you only generate the certificates locally, machines only trust *themselves* as localhost.

Comment: See [this thread](https://cabforum.org/pipermail/public/2015-June/005673.html) which discusses some issues with `localhost` which is why we definitely shouldn't be creating `localhost` certificates with "public" private keys. - "As a result, accessing "https://localhost", say, on a hostile WiFi access
point (such as your coffee shops) can be intercepted by a network attacker
and redirected to a site (or a certificate) of their choosing."

Comment: Did you ever get a working solution?

Comment: @Rajiv Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We solved this in the end;

We are using SignalR and we distribute/install a certificate on the clients that is bought specifically for this purpose.
So our setup installs both the application and the certificate and binds it to the OWIN server. We got most of the information on how to do this via this blog:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Sep/23/Hosting-SignalR-under-SSLhttps

It contains a detailed step-by-step description on how to get this to work.

**EDIT:**

Binding the certificate to the port is done by using the netsh command. We use InnoSetup to execute this for us. [Info on how to do this is here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate)

Please note that we use a single certificate, and the command needs the certificate key in order to bind it.
This might be an issue using multiple (different) certificates, I'm not sure if it's possible to extract the key from the certificate to dynamically issue the command for different certificates. For a single certificate we had only a single key, and that was hardcoded.

It might be possible to extract the key, [this is some info that might help in that regard.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getcerthashstring.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am actually doing the exact same steps and yes it works. For each client installation, I have a different certificate. I was interested to know if you could automate (by code) the "Binding certificate to SSL port" step?

Comment: @Rajiv I expanded my answer

Comment: Thank you very much! I shall try this and consider the feasibility of using same certificate in my case.